# What are the exact permissions I need to run the gsutil notification create command?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCS (Google Cloud Service) bucket and a Google PubSub topic, I want events from this bucket to automatically be sent to the PubSub topic.

When I run this command

```
gsutil notification create -t pubsub_topic_name -f json gs://bucket-name
```

I keep getting

```
AccessDeniedException: 403
```

What are the exact permissions I need to set for my user account so I can run that gsutil command?

Thanks
IS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always need ownership of the bucket (`storage.buckets.update`).

If the topic `pubsub_topic_name` doesn't exist, you need permission to create it ( `projects.topics.create` ).

You need permission to grant publish permission to a new service account (`projects.topics.setIamPolicy`).

Also, if you enable debug output in gsutil (use `gsutil -D notification create...`, you will probably get a better hint about exactly which call failed.